# script not conforming to the other css rules

Tags: javascript, html, css

So here I have my index.html, everything else excepts the  conforms to the css rules, but I have no idea why  isn't. Could someone explain why this is happening? :O

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
}

h1 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 300%;
}

h2 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 400%;
}

div.outer {
  background-color: #ffffff9d;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(153, 144, 144);
}

div.inner {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="sample"></div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1 class="top">Room Temp</h1>
    <h2>
      <script>
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('data', function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          document.getElementById('sample').innerHTML = data;
        });
      </script>
    </h2>
  </div>
```

Comment: *script not conforming to the other css rules* - why would script conform to the css rules?

Comment: Your "sample" `<div>` is *outside* the other two `<div>` elements, so the CSS rules for `div.outer` and `div.inner` have no effect on it.

Comment: @Konrad I would assume the end result of a script that is under another div class would use the properties assigned to those divs